# The position doesn't change when I use fseek()

Tags: c++, file, text, fseek

I want to make a function in a class, that allows me to display a line of text from a file at the current position. When I use `fseek()`, the `j` changes, but the output is the same.

```
void lecture(){
    static int j;
    char str[100];

    fp=fopen(name,"r");
    fseek(fp,j,SEEK_SET);
    if(feof(fp))
        cout<<"impossible de lire"<<endl;
    else{
        fscanf(fp,"%s\n",str);
        cout<<str<<endl;
        j+= strlen(str);
        cout<<j<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, why are you using C-style file I/O in C++? You should use the `std::ifstream` class instead. In any case, nothing is in this code is doing error handling? Did you check that `fopen()` is not failing? That `fseek()` is not failing()?` That `fscanf()` is not failing? Did you look at the actual contents of `str` to make sure they are what you are expecting?

Comment: the teatcher wanted that way

Comment: You probably do not want the `\n` in your `fscanf` format string. You should also close the file when you're done with it.

Comment: @chihebnouri then the teacher is not doing good. This is not the way to learn C++.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: Also, tell your teacher to teach you `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow or underflow.  The `std::string` can dynamically allocate space and is easier to pass to functions.

Comment: okay but for now i have to fix this code

Comment: Let's say that the first line in the file is "1\n". `fscanf` reads a single string "1", then the newline character. Two characters get read. Obviously, next time `j` must be 2, in order to resume reading from the file where it left off the last time. Can you point your finger to the exact line in the shown code that results in `j` changing from 0 to 2, and explain, exactly, how you believe this will happen?

Comment: read the docs on feof()